# Need help to address Error: "Could not load payment element - Is there a problem with your network connection?"

Tags: wordpress, error, stripe

Our charity Touching Base ([www.touchingbase.org](https://www.touchingbase.org) ) uses CiviCRM on Wordpress, with Stripe as our payment processor.
Everything is updated to the latest version, but when opening our CiviCRM Membership Contribute page it shows the Error message: *Could not load payment element - Is there a problem with your network connection?*

We only offer two payment options and payment by Credit card is the default option. If I select the non-default option and then re-select the credit card option the Stripe "payment element" suddenly appears as it should when initially opening the webpage and a test live payment by credit card worked.

People wanting to join as new members are complaining about it not working. As small unfunded charity with limited tech knowledge, we would greatly appreciate any insights into what's going on and how to fix it?

Cheers
Saul

Comment: Looks like it takes 5-6 seconds to load the card field when stripe is selected

Comment: add what version of civi and stripe you are using

Comment: Thanks, We're using CiviCRM 5.41.0 and Stripe 6.6.2.